# basic IF statement confusion

Tags: python

This is one problem I saw on Code War.

"takes a string input, and returns the first character that is not repeated anywhere in the string.
For example, if given the input 'stress', the function should return 't', since the letter t only occurs once in the string, and occurs first in the string.
As an added challenge, upper- and lowercase letters are considered the same character, but the function should return the correct case for the initial letter. For example, the input 'sTreSS' should return 'T'.
If a string contains all repeating characters, it should return an empty string ("") or None
"

And this following is one of the solutions, I can understand most of it, but it got me at the last line of code, how to make of "if singles else '' . Does it mean, `if singles` is equivalent of `if singles !=0` ?

```
def first_non_repeating_letter(string):
    singles = [i for i in string if string.lower().count(i.lower()) == 1]
    return singles[0] if singles else ''
```

Comment: It means if singles is not empty

Comment: You are correct. If singles has something, items, then it's considered Truthy.

Comment: This syntax (kind of) mimics ternary expressions in other languages (particularly Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
return singles[0] if singles else ''
```

So this is conditional expression which of the form

`return something if condition1 else return someotherthing`
This is equivalent as

```py
if condition1:
   return something
else:
   return someotherthing
```

In the given case `singles[0]` is returned if singles is not empty, otherwise the else part is executed.

That one line is same as

```py
if singles:
   return singles[0]
else:
   return ''
```

Note: `if singles` means whether singles is empty or not.

[image: List not empty print y else print n]

Comment: Thanks for all the explanation. I get it now. so basically the key point here is, in Python, empty is treated as False,  therefore when singles is not empty, `if singles:` is evaluated as True...

Comment: Coming from a mainly Java background I do find this something of an oddity in Python. If I have a variable V (in Python) that references an empty list then that variable does not equal None. But, if I write 'if V:' the test is not whether the variable is None but its type is taken into account (a list) and will return True if the list is not empty. This, in my opinion, supports the argument among many Python coders to be explicit in their 'if' statements. In this case 'if V is not None and len(V) > 0:' would make it absolutely clear what's being checked.

Comment: @AndyKnight--As [Opinions on truthiness across languages](https://dev.to/wrschneider/opinions-on-truthiness-across-languages) points out, coders more commonly want to distinguish between empty or non-empty strings or empty or a non-empty collection (i.e. when None is not a possibility).
The `if V...` is a concise way of making this test.  Why add the logic for checking if V is None when None not a possibility?  Meaning, we constructed a list and we simply want to check if it is empty or not.

Answer (score 2):

The last line:

```
return singles[0] if singles else ''
```

can be rewritten like this:

```
if singles:  # in fact if len(singles) > 0
  return singles[0]
else:
  return ''
```

You can read the [conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) section to learn more